# Resistance is futile

Tags: cipher

On the sunny morning of April 5th, 2063, an alien spaceship started orbiting the Earth. Among the cries of "It's an alien spaceship!" and "Ohm my god!" from the people, governments noticed that they were beaming down a colorful message:

[image: V over I equals?]

Unfortunately, because of interference from the atmosphere, they were only left with this small fragment.

***Can you decode the fragment, and hence guess the entire transmission?***

Comment: Do we assume aliens speak English here?

Comment: The decoded message will be in English, and clearly correct.

Comment: How do you beam down the color black? Alien technology?

Comment: Shouldn't brown-black-brown+black-green-black be brown-black-brown+green-black-gold or e.g. gray-black-black+red-green-black?  I didn't think the leftmost place was allowed to be black?

Comment: Technically the leftmost bar cannot be black in a real resistor, but I have some artistic license with the puzzle :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The date given, April 5 2063, is the [launch date of the Phoenix spaceship from Star Trek](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Phoenix).

The title "Resistance is futile" also alludes to [another famous Star Trek phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_%28Star_Trek%29#.22Resistance_is_futile.22). Therefore, the answer is likely to be related to the Star Trek franchise in one way or another.

Translating the code using [image: this table]

results in the text:

> 760 101+050 101+180
>
> 101+010 320 101+080
>
> 101+110 111 101+030
>
> 320 970 111 012 320 (interpreting the 9 as a blank breaks the message)

Interpreting the bars similar to the 3-bar resistor code (with the least significant digit encoding the exponent of 10 when 3 bars exist) results in:

> 76 100+5 100+18
>
> 100+1 32 100+8
>
> 100+11 110 100+3
>
> 32 97 110 100 32

which decodes to ASCII

> Live long and (?)

Assuming the context of Star Trek, the answer is probably

> [Live long and prosper](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Vulcan_salute)

Answer (score 13):

I cannot open the image, but clue for everyone who didn't notice:

> The header says RESISTANCE is futile and cries of 'OHM y god' OHM is a unit of resistance, it might be a clue

Comment: Wow, excellent! I was just about to edit out the extra M in "Ohm my god", assuming it was a typo - glad I didn't!

Comment: Another easter egg- The image description is "V over I equals?" - only noticed that because it failed to load the first time!