# Tonight is movie night

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, movies

Tonight I went to my friend's for a movie night and he asked me what we should watch.

As I was playful, I handed him the following picture so he could guess the movie:

[image]

He couldn't figure it out, so after a while I gave him the following hint:

> Tolerance is not important

But he was still stuck.

Could you help him find the movie?

Comment: I don't like riddles which require obscure domain knowledge like this.

Comment: @Philipp, Questions like these can be hard to *resist*

Comment: Had you seen [Tryth's very similar puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10341/resistance-is-futile) when you posted this? I haven't studied either of them closely enough to tell whether this should be closed as a duplicate, but am just leaving this comment so others are aware of the possible issue here.

Comment: @randal'thor No I didn't. I was surprised that it was so similar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The movie is:

> **Star Trek: First Contact** (1996)

The message is:

> **Resistance is futile**. Although this phrase was used in earlier Star Trek episodes, it was made more popular as the tagline of the 1996 film Star Trek: First Contact by the actor Jeff Coopwood who was the "Voice of the Borg".

The encoding uses:

> **resistor codes** as shown in the following chart. Per the hint, the tolerance band is absent. The resistor codes are then converted to ASCII characters as shown below.
>
>  [image: Resistor codes]

Comment: Was literally typing my answer as you posted. Damn :)

Comment: Beat me by about 30 sec.. I know I've seen this before though.

Comment: @Quark [Maybe because I had a very similar idea before](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10341/resistance-is-futile) :p

Comment: @Tryth ah that was it. Funny how although it wasn't space related, the message also matched (either coincidence or homage probably).

Comment: @Len that answer is right though... not sure how another would benefit.

Comment: @Tryth I thought it was original. I was wrong :(