# Meditative Futility

Tags: story, knowledge, cipher

I was working in a lab, late one night, when I happened upon a slip of paper stuck into my lab partner's desk.

I know, I know!  I shouldn't go poking around where I don't belong...

It was just....asking me to read it!  Well, now I regret it.  The paper is complete nonsense!  I bet it's some secret recipe, or -- no wait!! -- His plans for the next prank that he plans to pull on me!  If I can figure it out, now, before he gets back, tomorrow, I can try to stave off whatever he has planned, or even make it backfire!

Let's see, here.  I'll take a closer look...

> gngnbkvtrdbkgnbnbkogrdbkbuvtbkyegybkyewhbkyegybkgy
>   rdbkgnogbkogrdbkgygnbkgnogbkgnbnbkbugybkogrdbkyewh
>   bkvtgybkogrdbkgngnbkvtrdbkyewhbkgnogbkogrdbkgybkbk
>   gygnbkwhbkbkwhbkbkyewhbkgnbnbkgyrdbkgnbnbkogrdbkgy
>   bubkgnbnbkogrdbkgybubkgnbnbkgyrdbkgywhbkogrdbkyewh
>   bkvtvtbkgybkbkyegybkgyrdbkgngnbkgnrdbkvtgybkgngnbk

Well...There definitely seems to be a pattern here - but I don't know what it is.  This is going to take me all night to solve, isn't it...

...I might as well get to it...

Comment: You've tagged it knowledge, what knowledge is needed?

Comment: I'd rather not give that hint, just yet, unless it's needed.

Comment: Aaah ok, it would spoil it I get that

Comment: *Does a google search*. *Only results which come up is this page*. ^^'

Comment: It caught on in a flash...

Comment: @MiloPrice Nononono.  There's no monster mash here!  :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution:

> 7H3 C010R5 U53D 1N 7H15 PUZZ13 W3R3 V3RY 1MP0R74N7

Or:

> The colors used in this puzzle were very important

Decoding:

> These are 3-band resistor color codes. The corresponding resistance in ohms is the ASCII code of the corresponding character.
>  The two-letter abbreviations in the text are interpreted (per the [IEC 60757 Standard](http://www.linzi.hu/Katalogus/2008-2009/eng/X057%20Colour%20Abbreviations%20according%20to%20VDE%20and%20IEC.pdf) as:
>  bn = Brown,
>  rd = Red,
>  og = Orange,
>  ye = Yellow,
>  gn = Green,
>  bu = Blue,
>  vt = Violet,
>  gy = Gray,
>  bk = Black

Comment: Oh no!  All this time spent, and wasting my time solving the puzzle was the prank, all along!!  I'm going home, now..

Comment: I was thinking of that code,  but it did't click.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Resistance is Futile! - hint in the title.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Ohm..... Ohm.... Ohm....

Comment: @ChrisCudmore There's [another puzzle with that title](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10341/)!

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I think it's fine now. I thought I was missing a few letters, but it turns out it's indeed PUZZ13R3

Comment: Oh. So i *was* missing a few letters. Sorry about that.

Comment: Np - good job on solving it

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I think the question is actually missing those letters - I had the same ones missing when I solved it, and the other answer has 47 sets of 3 whereas the complete phrase has 50 characters.

Comment: @Zandar I checked, a third time, with a different method, and was able to pick up those three numbers.  I guess the first methods I used weren't enough.  Sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 8):

Does this help anyone 3x47 grid.  ?

> [image]

Comment: I see the light

Comment: Agreed with humn, 47x3 might be better.